# Kinect V2 vs PyKinect2 : difference between depth image

Tags: python-3.x, kinect-v2

I'm currently working on the kinect V2 to have access to the depth image. I use the library in python PyKinect2 that help me to have this images.

My first problem is :

-> I run KinectStudio 2, and look for the depth image, i look for the implementation of the PyKinect2 and i have a different image. How that could be possible ?

-> To have access to the depth of specific point called X(x,y),  I use the method MapColorFrameToDepthSpace, and i manage to have some coordinates that will help me to have the distance on the depth frame. 
Is this assertion is correct ?

to get the depth image :

```
 def draw_depth_frame(self, frame):
     depth_frame = frame.reshape((424, 512,-1)).astype(np.uint8)
     return depth_frame
```

the image from kinect 2 :

[image: Kinect Image Depth from Kinect Studio]

the image from kinect 2 with color ramp :

[image: the image from kinect 2 with color ramp]

the image from pyKinect 2

[image: pyKinect 2]

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake about this,

When i use this

```
depth_frame = frame.reshape((424, 512,-1)).astype(np.uint8)
```

This line is in fact wrong.

The depth is not mapped on a uint8, but on a uint16.

By performing the reshape, i have a "lost" of information about the distance, i have only value as 255, so not very useful.

example: 1600 as a distance, was considered as 255, and because of this line, it gives me the third depth image on my previous post. SO the correction is simply something :

```
depth_frame = frame.reshape((424, 512,-1)).astype(np.uint16)
```